# When trying to install requests in windows it is giving me a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, python-requests, installation

It is telling me that "install" is an unresolved reference???  I have tried all of the suggestions presented, and this is frustrating as I am attempting to finish a course.

Comment: How are you trying to install the module?

Comment: you seem to be trying to install it from python, you need to do it from the command line

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

It appears that you are in Python console and trying to install it in there. That is possible with iPython console using `!`:

```
!pip install requests
```

or using subprocesses(which is just overkill). Running in CMD.exe, or Powershell,  assuming Python is on your Path, ought to work.